# Num of occurances where Column difference in DataFrame satisfies a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, count

I have a Dataframe with lots of Rows, and I am just looking for a count of the rows which fulfil a criteria.
Data snippet:

mydf:

```
           Date      Time    Open    High     Low   Close
143  07:08:2015  14:55:00  300.10  300.45  300.10  300.45
144  07:08:2015  15:00:00  300.50  300.95  300.45  300.90
145  07:08:2015  15:05:00  300.90  301.20  300.75  300.90
146  07:08:2015  15:10:00  300.85  301.40  300.75  301.40
147  07:08:2015  15:15:00  301.40  301.60  301.20  301.55
148  07:08:2015  15:20:00  301.45  301.55  301.10  301.40
```

My current Code, first splits the required columns into 2 series, and then Counts the number of occurances of the Last 6 elements

```
openpr = mydf['Open'] 
closepr = mydf['Close'] # 2 Series, one for Open and One for Close data 
differ  = abs(closepr - openpr) #I have a series list with absolute Difference.
myarr = differ[142:].values == 0 # last X elements  
sum(myarr) #Num of occurances with Zero Difference.
```

From what I understand there is a much way of achieving the above result with minimal code and directly using the DF itself.

TIA

Comment: Use `(df.Close - df.Open).eq(0).sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need compare by `eq` for `==` with last `6` values by [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tail.html) and count values by `sum`:

```
out = mydf['Close'].tail(6).eq(mydf['Open'].tail(6)).sum()
```

Your solution should be changed for last 6 values, also added [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) for less `()` in code:

```
out = mydf['Close'].tail(6).sub(mydf['Open'].tail(6)).abs().eq(0).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to difference then take absolute value only to find where zero.  Just find where they're equal in the first place.

#### `eval`

This is a `pandas.DataFrame` method that allows for strings to represent formulas.  It turns out to be pretty quick on large datasets.  I find it very readable in many circumstances.

```
mydf.tail(6).eval('Close == Open').sum()
```

If you needed to be within some delta and had to difference the columns

```
mydf.tail(6).eval('abs(Close - Open) < 1e-6').sum()
```

---

#### `isclose`

This is a Numpy function that acknowledges that floats are inherently a little off due to lack of precision.  So we just want to know if values are close enough.

```
np.isclose(mydf.Open.tail(6), mydf.Close.tail(6)).sum()
```

However, for determining if the difference is within some delta is easier when using `isclose` because of the built in tolerance argument

```
np.isclose(mydf.Open.tail(6), mydf.Close.tail(6), atol=1e-6).sum()
```

Comment: If I want the difference to be Dynamic (.05 for e.g.) , I don't **think** i can use this code.

Comment: Not true.  I'll adjust both options to demonstrate.

Comment: @suraj_Blore post has been updated.  jezrael's answer is a fine answer.  hope this is helpful as well.

Comment: Yes this Answer if Fine.